# Обработка ошибки при получении ответа от сервера. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Подскажите каким способом можно обработать полученный ответ от сервера и в зависимости от ответа перенаправить пользователя на нужную страницу. Не могу сообразить как это сделать. 
В общем суть такова:
Есть html форма.

```
<form name="codeForm" novalidate>
   <input name="code" type="text" placeholder="Enter your code" ng-model="confirm.code" required>
   <a href="/nextpage"><button ng-click="send()" ng-disabled="codeForm.$invalid">Next</button></a>
</form>
```

При нажатии на button, данные которые были заполнены в input отправляются на сервер:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('myFactory', myFactory);

function myFactory($http, $q) {
    return {
       confirmPhoneNumber: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: "http://example:8080/mimimi/",
                method: "POST",
                data: data, 
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
                console.log(data)
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.reject(status);
                console.log(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

После мы получаем ответ, правильно ли пользователь ввел данные или нет. В случае успеха возвращает: success: true, в противном случае: success: false.

ВОПРОС: Если ответ false, как оставить пользователя на этой же странице? и в случае c true, разрешить переход на следующею (ссылка которая прикручена к button). Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно это сделать, или поделитесь ссылками на подходящие статьи!

P.S: использую роутинг ui-router.

Comment: Что же мешает сделать проверку в send() и там же получить значение href?

Comment: во-первых: _$http_ - уже возвращает promise, нет нужды делать его еще и вручную через  `$q.defer()`, во-вторых - использовать блочный элемент button внутри inline - ссылки как-то не очень, и непонятно зачем. Обработчик клика можно навесить и на ссылку

Comment: ну и еще стоит добавить функцию `send`

Comment: Зачем вы вообще используете `$q.defer()` - если функция `$http()` уже возвращает вам обещание?

Comment: @PavelMayorov То есть, тут можно обойтись и без $q.defer() значит я неправильно понимаю для чего он нужен. Просто раннее у меня не получалось извлечь полученные данные и работать с ними без использования $q.defer(). Если не затруднит, может объясните вкратце когда его надо использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не там проверку делаете. Проверять данные надо в resolve ui-router. Если вернется true, то переходим на страницу.